# React-Player gets stuck on fullscreen mode in mobile

Tags: reactjs, vimeo, vimeo-player, react-player

I'm using React-Player as background for a landing page, but when using it on a mobile (not on desktop) it will sometimes, not always, go on fullscreen mode and get stuck there.

The video I'm using is from vimeo, so I'm not sure if the problem is with my ReactPlayer configuration, or whether it is an issue with the vimeo API / SDK.

```
      <ReactPlayer
        key={`video-${videoIdx}`}
        url={videoSrcUrl}
        className="react-player"
        playing={true}
        controls={false}
        muted={true}
        config={{
          vimeo: {
            iframeParams: { fullscreen: 0 },
            autoplay: true,
            playsinline: true,
            muted: true
          },
        }}
        onReady={() => {
          setReady(true)
        }}
        onEnded={() => {
          setReady(false)
        }}
      />
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you get any solution?